# Subfolder as Magento storeview

Tags: magento-1.9, htaccess, .htaccess

I am trying to access a store view in Magento 1.9.1.1 from a subfolder.

I have:

```
www.webshop1.nl => store_1 + default
www.webshop2.nl => store_2 + storeview_NL
www.webshop2.nl/en => store_2 + storeview_EN
```

The first two stores are working now, but I cannot manage to get the folder as a storeview.
In the Magento URL settings I set all the parameters.

This is my htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)webshop1.nl
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:default]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)webshop2.nl
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/en/$
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:storeview_en]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)webshop2.nl
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:storeview_nl]
```

What am I doing wrong?